# Illegal State Exception In JSF 2.0 Login Validation. Why?

Tags: jsf, authentication, jsf-2

I tried to redirect the users who directly enter the URL of the home page without logging in.

So I attached this event to the home page.

```
<f:metadata>
       <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{login_bean.verifyAccessOut}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

Inside that login_bean I have this method...

```
public void verifyAccessOut() {

    ExternalContext context2 = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        if(logstatus==false)
        try {
            message="Unauthorized Access: Please Login First";
            style="color:red;text-decoration:blink";
            context2.redirect("index.xhtml");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HomeBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

It throws an illegal state exception. like this,

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:522)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.redirect(ExternalContextImpl.java:572)
    at org.mit.care.LoginBean.verifyAccessIn(LoginBean.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:43)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:72)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2345)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:1993)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:1941)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:285)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:243)
    at javax.faces.application.Application.publishEvent(Application.java:1660)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Why is this happening? Why cant i use the external context to redirect to the necessary page at the prerender view event?

Please help me to understand about this problem. Thank you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view is not the right place to control the request. It might be too late to change the response, because the view itself is part of the response. The enduser has already obtained a part of the response from the server at the point this line of code is to be executed. This is a point of no return. The server cannot take the already sent response back and send a different one. You need to do the job *before* any bit is been sent to the response.

You normally use a `Filter` for this, which runs in the very early beginning of the request. Put all restricted pages in a certain folder, something like `/private/*`, `/secured/*`, `/app/*` or whatever and map a `Filter` on that URL pattern which does the following job in `doFilter()` method:

```
if (((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute("user") == null) {
    ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("/home");
} else {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

This example assumes that the logged-in user is present as a session attribute with the name `user`. It can even be a session scoped JSF managed bean.

Comment: now I understand clearly. Thank you...  By the way what is your knowledge source for JSF 2.0. I don't think the complete reference explains this much. :)